# fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet

Tags: git, macos, installation, terminal

I try to install brew to install python libs using the code

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

But I get this error

```
error: 1262 bytes of body are still expected MiB | 11.00 KiB/s 
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
Failed during: git fetch --force origin
```

tried the gpt solution to it but it didn't work.
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
This will increase the size of the buffer that Git uses when fetching data from the remote repository, which may help to resolve the issue if it is caused by large files or a slow connection.

I also tried to run this

```
export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
export GIT_TRACE=1
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

I got the same error. Keep in mind that my internet is working properly and I am browsing the web.

Comment: *Keep in mind that my internet is working properly and I am browsing the web.* The fact that you can browse the web doesn't mean that your Internet connection is 100% working. You mention macos in tags (and brew, which doesn't seem to be for Windows) so you'll have bypassed one of the common problems with Windows systems where certain network drivers have bugs that only affect *some* software. (Such bugs can occur on macs as well of course, they're just not *common* right now, unlike Windows.)

Comment: But some middleware (including some VPNs)—hardware and/or software boxes—will corrupt some data, so that too can be a source of problems. In any case, this isn't a *programming* issue, it's a network operation one: you'll want superuser.com or similar.

Answer (score 6):

You can try changing the compression configuration:

```
git config --global core.compression 0
```

Comment: On Windows 11, I also had to disable Windows Defender's Real Time Protection.

Comment: TY @juniel_katarn, same. Using Git-for-Windows 2.43.0 and disabling Defender real-time protection allowed me to `git submodule foreach git reset --hard` to finish checking out my submodules.

Answer (score 4):

Looking for solutions to this on Windows 10 took me to:

- Original reported issue but closed - https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1322
- Followup and still open issue - https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/issues/667

The current workaround appears to be to use PuTTY/Pageant instead of open-ssh tools on windows.

Maybe this will help you or someone else track progress on a real fix if it is on Windows. I don't get this issue on my Ubuntu system.