error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 - send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
git push causes the following:
Enumerating objects: 1833, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1833/1833), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1813/1813), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (1816/1816), 2.00 GiB | 1.23 MiB/s, done.
Total 1816 (delta 523), reused 639 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

What I tried:
setting the buffer size to 500MB:
git config http.postBuffer 524288000

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78393464/17421351 says that Github has a hard-limit of 2GB per push, but my commit would be exactly 2GB, as you can see. It might be a little bit more, but GitHub is generous with it's limits normally.
I also tried (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67390274/17421351) setting verbose logging logs the following:
set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
set GIT_TRACE=1
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

logs:
17:29:25.780117 http.c:827              => Send header:
17:38:29.033387 http.c:868              == Info: Send failure: Connection was reset
17:38:29.033387 http.c:868              == Info: OpenSSL SSL_write: Connection was reset, errno 10054
17:38:29.033387 http.c:868              == Info: Connection #1 to host github.com left intact
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was reset
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (1816/1816), 2.00 GiB | 3.29 MiB/s, done.
Total 1816 (delta 523), reused 639 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
17:39:33.211700 pkt-line.c:86           packet:          git> 0000
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

No, there are no files larger than 100MB in my repo. I checked using the following Powershell-script:
param (
    [string]$Path = (Get-Location) # Default to current location if no path is specified
)

# Get files larger than 100MB, because they can not be uploaded to Github without lfs.
$largeFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Length -gt 100MB }

if ($largeFiles) {
    $largeFiles | Select-Object FullName, Length
} else {
    Write-Output "There are no files larger than 100MB in the specified path."
}

I also tried setting git config pack.window 1, which made it worse, I think (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74612545/17421351)
18:10:59.781010 http.c:827              <= Recv header:
18:10:59.781541 http.c:868              == Info: HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
18:10:59.781541 http.c:868              == Info: abort upload after having sent 2148729015 bytes
18:10:59.781541 http.c:868              == Info: Connection #1 to host github.com left intact
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (1816/1816), 2.06 GiB | 1.27 MiB/s, done.
Total 1816 (delta 341), reused 639 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
18:11:05.773582 pkt-line.c:86           packet:          git> 0000
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

I am not using any VPN right now and I am not using any Firewall other than the Windows Defender one right now.
Disabling compression using git config core.compression 0 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75102390/17421351) logs the following (doesn't look like the limit is actually 2GB):
18:15:08.508428 http.c:827              => Send header:
18:24:22.152359 http.c:868              == Info: Send failure: Connection was reset
18:24:22.152359 http.c:868              == Info: OpenSSL SSL_write: Connection was reset, errno 10054
18:24:22.152359 http.c:868              == Info: Connection #0 to host github.com left intact
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was reset
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (1816/1816), 2.31 GiB | 4.10 MiB/s, done.
Total 1816 (delta 0), reused 639 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
18:24:40.334565 pkt-line.c:86           packet:          git> 0000
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

